# LibGdx - Add AdMob to game

Tags: android, libgdx, admob

I spent all day trying to find an up-to-date example of how to add AdMob to LibGdx, I want to add it to Android to start with.

I managed to create an Android app with ads without a problem, however with LibGdx I can't find imports such as:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

And many of the other steps from the Google tutorial gives errors.

The most complete guide I could find on LibGdx Admob intigration was here:

> https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx

However I cannot get this example to work, I don't know if its outdated but for example I cant find the imports mentioned above or `IActivity`which it implements. The tutorial is so different from the "full code" example on the bottom which makes it quite confusing. And it doesnt mention what imports/dependencies are needed.

Is there any example out there that works? I just want to get started, then I usually figure things out. So any example would do.

Comment: the guide you've pasted is outdated..it is relevant for the old admobs..you should use the google mobile ads..check here https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Mobile-Ads-in-Libgdx-%28replaces-deprecated-AdMob%29

Comment: Thanks, changed to that and works nicely :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this dependency for those imports you listed:

`com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.3.0`

I'm not sure how it works as I've never implemented it with or without LibGdx but this is Google's [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) for it.

Comment: I just now changed from `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0` to `com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0`. And it works. For some reason "-ads" didnt work